# Print PDF file using PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to print a PDF file using PHP? How?

I do not want to show any dialog or anything, I just want to execute the PHP file and make it print a PDF file for me.

The PHP file will be executed server side.

Comment: On the server on which PHP is running, or on the client which is visiting a website generated by PHP? I'm guessing the latter, in which case: No. Do you think it'd be a good idea if a website was able to just print anything without confirmation?

Comment: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/

Comment: @deceze on the server

Comment: So, you want to print from PHP to a printer hooked up to the server? Have you tried any of the related questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841720/printing-to-printers-in-php?

Comment: I assume you wanted to convert php output to a pdf file. If so check this http://www.fpdf.org/. Next time please be clear on what you want.

Comment: @deceze You raise a valid point, in the situation that I produced something like this was on a seperate virtual Apache host which two people in the HR office had control over, the only constraint which we had to take into account was a duplicate print request from both of the members that had access to such application. that was the only constraint

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, I did this as an addition for an internal system.

The approach that I done was done using the brother printer drivers (because the printers inhouse was of the brother manufacturer).

The operating system that developed on was a Linux Redhat server. So I would check the printers manufacturer website to see if there is drivers available on either a windows or linux solution, read the documentation and perform a `exec();` call using the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't (in the browser).

In that case, you can either:

- Display the PDF in-line in a capable browser (where the user will have to choose to print --or-- confirm a print request/dialog)
- Offer the file as a download (where the user will have to open the PDF with a suitable viewer AND choose to print it)

You can on the server, using `shell_exec()`/`exec()` as has been pointed out in another answer, but doing so isn't easy as servers won't necessarily have the required drivers (or network capacity) to do so.

Comment: It is possible to print a file from PHP

Comment: I presume you mean using `shell_exec()` etc?